# Bulma: banner on top of navbar when at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, bulma

I am trying to make an Wordpress Theme using the Bulma framework with a banner on top of my menu. I have tried the following with the **navbar is-fixed-top** class under a **navbar** class to get the look I desire but the **navbar is-fixed-top** still shows above **navbar** when I write some JS to change the CSS when at the top of the page but it still stays with the **is-fixed-top** on top. I might just be missing something simple but any help will be great. I am adding snipes of my code but the content has been changed.

header.php

```
...
<body>
  <header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" id="banner">
      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
            <h1 class="title"><?php bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-start">
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <?php
            if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
              the_custom_logo();
            }
           ?>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-end">
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
              <p class="title is-5">Mailling address</p>
              <p>P.O. Box 1234</p>
              <p>Test, ST 12345</p>
            </div><!-- /column-->
            <div class="column">
              <p class="title is-5">Physical address</p>
              <p>1234 Foobar Ave.</p>
              <p>Test, ST 12345</p>
            </div><!-- /column-->
          </div> <!-- /columns -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar is-fixed-top" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
      </div>
      <?php if( is_front_page() ) {?>
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#1">1</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#2">2</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#3">3</a>
        </div> <!-- /navbar-start  -->
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#4">4</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#5">5</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#6">6</a>
        </div> <!-- /navbar-end -->
      <?php }
      else {?>
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#1">1</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#2">2</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#3">3</a>
        </div> <!-- /navbar-start  -->
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#4">4</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#5">5</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" herf="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#6">6</a>
        </div> <!-- /navbar-end -->
      <?php
      } ?>
      <div class="navbar-end">
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /navbar-menu -->
  </nav>
</div><!-- /container -->
</header>
<div class="body">
```

foo.js

```
if (document.body.scrollTop === 0)
{
  document.getElementById('topnavbar').style.top =
  document.getElementById('banner').height() + '!important';
}
else {
 document.getElementById('topnavbar').style.top =
  '0 !important';
}
```

style.css

```
#topnavbar {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I have Tried a few other ways but none of them work.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.. you want the banner above the nav at all times? And when scrolling the problem is that the nav jumps to the top above the banner?

Comment: `.affix` ? Are you trying to combine bootstrap with bulma without adapting either one? just assuming...

Comment: @sol I want the banner above the nav when at the top of the page, otherwise I want just the nav to be sticky and the banner to disappear.

Comment: @Chay22 sorry must of copied the wrong attempt need to find the right one and will fix. I had about 100 attempts, so code is messy at this point.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve to be precise? Remove `.is-fixed-top` when certain event occurs? `.is-fixed-top` makes the element `fixed`, it does the right job, tho.

Comment: @Chay22 I am trying to get the navbar to be sticky when the banner is not in place. `.is-fixed-top` makes a navbar sticky but it is above the banner as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom solution for your fixed navbar, instead of trying to tweak the `.is-fixed-top` modifier.

First, get the height of the banner. Then, when the user scrolls past this height, add a 'fixing' class to your nav.

Demo below...

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLorku77/6/)

```js
var bannerHeight = $('#banner').height();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > bannerHeight) {
    $('#topnavbar').addClass('affix');
  } else {
    $('#topnavbar').removeClass('affix');
  }
});
```

```css
.banner-demo {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}

#topnavbar {
  background: pink;
}

#topnavbar.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" id="banner">
      <div class="banner-demo">BANNER</div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" id="topnavbar">
      <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#1">1</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#2">2</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#3">3</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-start  -->
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#4">4</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#5">5</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#6">6</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-end -->

        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#1">1</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#2">2</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#3">3</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-start  -->
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#4">4</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#5">5</a>
          <a class="navbar-item" herf="<?php echo get_home_url();?>#6">6</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-end -->

        <div class="navbar-end">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /navbar-menu -->
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</header>
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni non, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. non, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod,
  expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore,
  inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto,
  facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem
  ipsum d molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis
  ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae
  a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio.
  Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem
  ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect
  molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni,
  vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero
  error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia
  quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem
  ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect
  molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni,
  vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero
  error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia
  quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem
  ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate
  unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in
  enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis
  vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, vonon, dolor tempore, autem odit voluptate unde neque numquam minus maxime quis ullam ipsum eos est repellat, architecto, facilis nulla asperiores.Lorem ipsum dolor sitsit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur
  sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, voRecusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem
  quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum!
  Magni, voluptatum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima hic deserunt odio quibusdam eos vel, doloribus cumque ab iusto voluptatibus odit sed dicta molestias porro quidem fugiat eum delectus eligendi! amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quod, expedita, modi. Recusandae a libero error natus tempore, harum eveniet nobis in enim distinctio, voluptas. Veritatis autem quam, molestias iusto recusandae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores facere consequatur
  sint tempore, inventore distinctio. Mollitia quasi, quidem aut dolorem incidunt perferendis vitae deleniti ad officia, veritatis ipsum! Magni, voluptatum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima hic deserunt odio quibusdam eos
  vel, doloribus cumque ab iusto voluptatibus odit sed dicta molestias porro quidem fugiat eum delectus eligendi!</div>
```